# Cut and export command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am working on a shell script which contains following piece of code. 
I don't understand these lines, mostly the cut command and export command. Can any one help me... 
Also please point me to a better linux command reference.
Thanks in advance!

```
# determine sum of 60 records
awk '{ 
    if (substr($0,12,2) == "60" || substr($0,12,2) == "78") \
            print $0 
}'< /tmp/checks$$.1 > /tmp/checks$$.2

rec_sum =`cut -c 151-160 /tmp/checks$$.2 | /u/fourgen/cashnet/bin/sumit`

export rec_sum
```

Inside my sumit script following is the code

```
awk '{ total += $1}
END {print total}' $1
```

---

Let me show my main script prep_chk

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""} {if (substr($0,12,2) == "60" && substr($0,151,1) == "-") \
        { print substr($0,1,11), "78", substr($0,14) } \
    else \
        { print $0 } \
    }' > /tmp/checks$$.1

# determine count of non-header record
rec_cnt=`wc -l /tmp/checks$$.1`
rec_cnt=`expr "$rec_cnt - 1"`
export rec_cnt

# determine sum of 60 records
awk '{ if (substr($0,12,2) == "60" || substr($0,12,2) == "78") \
    print $0 }'< /tmp/checks$$.1 > /tmp/checks$$.2
rec_sum=`cut -c 151-160 /tmp/checks$$.2 | /u/fourgen/cashnet/bin/sumit`
export rec_sum

# make a new header record and output it
head -1 /tmp/checks$$.1 | awk '{ printf("%s%011.11d%05.5d%s\n", \
    substr($0,1,45), rec_sum, rec_cnt, substr($0,62)) }' \
    rec_sum="$rec_sum" rec_cnt="$rec_cnt"

# output everything else sorted by tran code
grep -v "%%%%%%%%%%%" /tmp/checks$$.1 | cut -c 1-150 | sort -k 1.12,13
```

Comment: Better compared to what? Did you read the man page? For example `man cut`?

Comment: I am not a linux user and I don't know waht is a man page! Also I am not executing these scripts. I am just rewriting it in PHP.

Comment: Google for 'man cut' or type it in a shell

Comment: Ya I got the docs. Let me refer it. Thank you Matteo

Comment: I googled before getting this reference; But I didn't find this man docs

Comment: It means cut 10 character from a file; then what it says after the operator | ?

Comment: The `|` sends the output to the next command. From the path `sumit` seems a custom program.

Comment: Note that there should not be a space between the `rec_sum` and the `=` in the line with the `cut` command.  (Actually, inspection of the code shows it is a tab, but that shouldn't be there either!)

Comment: Thank you I have a sumit shell script in the path mentioned!

Comment: This is not a question `cut` does exactly as describe in the doc *i.e the man pages* and it does it well.

Answer (score 2):

`cut -c` cuts text from a given position in a file, in this case characters 151 to 160 in the file `/tmp/checks$$.2`. This string is piped to some code called `submit` which produces some output.
That output is then assigned to the environment variable `rec_sum`. The `export` command makes this variable available to be used through the system, for example in another shell script.

Edit:
If that's all you have inside your submit script it simply adds on the string you pass it, which it seems must be a number, to some value total and prints the number it was passed. It seems like there must be some more code inside that script otherwise it would be a bit of an over complicated way to do it.

Comment: Please look at my main script prep_chk

Comment: I think I've given you a decent amount of help here explaining various parts of "your" script. If I were you I'd find an online tutorial about awk. It looks very complicated and tricky, but once you get the hang of it it's really powerful. Also you always have the man pages which are very well written, and for anything else there's google. If you get stuck play around with individual commands from the script in the terminal.